# Avoid reopen datepicker after date selection in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

when I select a date, the datepicker reopen itself because I added $(this).focus(); in onSelect. How I can to resolve this issue? [(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/VZts7/61/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect : function(x, u){
     $(this).focus();   
    }
});
```

I want that focus must. I cannot remove that focus. Please tell me some solution for that without removing that focus.

Comment: it is working perfectly in fiddle..what is the problem???

Comment: works fine in chrome.

Comment: its happening only in IE browser

Comment: you should add the version @VinothBabu

Answer (score -1):

Please note that After jquery ui datepicker selection, blur and change events fire before focus is returned to the input field, there is always problem with focus event on IE.

The Fix is given below

```
//Example using triggerHandler 
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect : function(x, u){
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        },
        onClose: function(dateText) {
             $(this).triggerHandler("focus");
             $(this).triggerHandler("blur");
        }
    });
});
```

This work for me,
refer

> //Example using triggerHandler
>   http://jsfiddle.net/shaikhimran786/w6fvuL18/

Use triggerHandler to solve the issue.

The triggerHandler() method triggers the specified event for the selected element.

This method is similar to the trigger() method, except that trigger() also triggers the default behavior of an event (like form submission).

and another solution is

```
//Example using hide datepicker 
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect : function(x, u){
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }
    });
    $('.dp').on('change', function () {
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
});
```

refer below link for

> //Example using hide datepicker 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/shaikhimran786/xj9tkvtd/

Hope this fix will help you to solve your problem.